# CURL alternative in ReactJS, Download Image from a URL in a Folder

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to download the image in a folder from a URL in ReactJS https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1871/44381239451_8e000b4b26.jpg

Here is how my screen looks like. Being a PHP developer I know how to fetch, download the image in CURL (very easy). ReactJs I cannot find any library to do it, any code will be helpful.The download image button should Save the image on the Server in a folder

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the behaviour that you're after? Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want a button to download an image url? This is something that you can just do with html, if I'm understanding you correctly

Comment: @BrettEast the download image button should Save the images on the Server folder, should not download locally.